# useState value not rendering in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am an absolute beginner with React, I have a component where I need to render the value of a state to the Dom but it doesnt work let me show you my code.

**Links.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Collapse } from 'antd'

const Links = () => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>asd2</div>
      <div>{ isMobile }</div>
      <div>asd5</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Links
```

I am using it like

footer.jsx

```
import Links from './links'

const Footer = ({
  globalData,
  user
}) => {
return(
<Links/>
)

}
```

it does render the text **asd2** and **asd5** meaning the component itself works just not the state value. I've looked everywhere this is how everybody does it .What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It’s a Boolean. You have to convert it to a string

Comment: `false`, `null` & `undefined` these values are not rendered, if want to render `false` make it a string, `"false"`.

Comment: Lol, I came from a vue background I am finding these types of things which makes me wanna go back :')

Comment: Reason being is to allow this kind of expressions `{isLink && <Link to="locaction" />}`. Here if `isLink` is `false`, `null` or `undefined` then nothing is rendered. If `isLink` is a truthy value, then `<Link to="location" />` is rendered.

Comment: Ahhh, thats a point!

Comment: @DanielA.White can you please write down your answer so i can mark it?

Comment: For more info check out [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) where the behaviour is explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
<div>{ isMobile }</div>
```

Try this

```
<div>{ isMobile.toString()}</div>
```

Or this

```
<div>{ isMobile ? "true" : "false"}</div>
```

Even this:

```
<div>{`${isMobile}`}</div>
```

Type `boolean` cannot be rendered in JSX.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `isMobile` it to a string. false, null & undefined these values are not rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can't render a Boolean.
Use it like this:

```
{ isMobile.toString() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't render a Boolean value. Use it like this:
`{ isMobile.toString() }`